Ignore sub-dependencies in pyproject.toml
A package I want to include in my pyproject.toml, itself depends on torch, which I don't want automatically installing since it takes up a lot of space and my currently installed version already works with it.
So, I want to emulate the functionality of the --no-dependencies pip install flag, instead with configuration in my pyproject.toml file for that specific package.
I was unable to find any information online on how to do this.
